# App qualification process for Over the air install in android

Tags: android, google-play, installation, over-the-air

According to the android developer documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/android-app-installs#app_requirements), Over the Air install is available based on some app requirements mentioned below :

"*For your app to be eligible for this feature, it must be published in the Google Play store, be free, and it must meet a quality threshold. This threshold is determined by Google and is subject to change. New apps might take some time to meet the quality threshold*"

My app is free and published on play store. My query is regarding ***quality threshold*** mentioned above.

1. How does one know if their app meets this threshold?
2. Also, for new apps is their a way to find out when this feature will work?

I could not find this anywhere in the documentation. If anyone has any idea, please shed some light on this.

Thanks in advance!